# Application crashes, because of a high input

Tags: c++, crash-dumps

My application is terminating with signal 11 - segmentation fault.

Core dump has been generated, and it say the following:

```
#0  Players::shareExperience (this=0x7fd3f8187600,
    experience=401912970206.76483154296875, m=<value optimized out>,
    multiplied=<value optimized out>) at players.cpp:130
130                     (*it)->gainSharedExperience(tmpExperience, m                                                                                                                               , multiplied);
```

This happends, when player is killing a monster, and get high amount of experience.

In my opinion, it shouldn't crash, because the expierience on `130` line is a `long double` , so it should handle that.

Is there any way, to handle that big amount of numbers? This is probably the expierience that player get when monster it killed: `experience=401912970206.76483154296875` isnt `long double` enough for that?

Comment: Your problem isn't what you think it is. Floating point overflow does not lead to segmentation fault. And anyway, this is a small value for floating point, no overflow here. Without seeing your code we can't help.

Comment: "In my opinion, it shouldn't crash" - I cracked up right there. Why don't you debug what happens, instead of decide what should happen? May I suggest `valgrind` - and posting some code?

Comment: Why are you concentrating on a double? Does `*it` yield a correct pointer?

Comment: The segmentation fault has absolutely nothing to do with the double. You are accessing memory that you shouldnt. Check what memory you access, and then find out why it is wrong to access it and why you tried.

Comment: Do you know what the value of `it` was?  You're dereferencing it and using the value, so if it's invalid that could be a segfault.  Heck, what's the type of `it`?  If it's a pointer, you need to say `it->` or `(*it).`.

Comment: Guys, here is my `void` you was asking for: 130 line is where the `(*it)` is, http://pastebin.com/EUXcNzq0

Comment: @Cyclone: is `PlayerVector` a `std::vector<Player*>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That fault is not from the large long double value, it is most likely from dereferencing an invalid iterator in `it` (or an iterator with an invalid pointer value).

Comment: Well, but it does crash only, when player is killing a monster with experience like: `3890000000000000` in other cases, when experience is smaller (like 38900000000) it doesnt crash.

Comment: @Cyclone Why ask for help and then discount it when it arrives? +1

Comment: @Cyclone I suppose the real problem lies elsewhere: some stack corruption, for example. This particular value of `experience` may unmask the problem, but that's all.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I did not, I'm just tryin to do everything that people say, so I posted by code in the comment.

Comment: @Cyclone, but we still don't know if *it is a valid pointer or not. Most likely, it is not.

Comment: @MichaelGoldshteyn Yes, ofc. it is a valid pointer. As I've told before, it is working fine, but "small" amount of experience, problem comes out, when player is receiving large experience value.

Comment: If it really was a valid pointer, why would there be a seg fault there? The other memory reads are local variables and so we can rule them out as suspects.

Comment: @Cyclone: It seems that large amounts of experience are invalidating your `Player*`.  Look for places where `memberList` is modified, and one of those places is giving it an invalid pointer, or altering a pointer making it invalid.